# how to stream video in direct connection between 2 clients

Tags: javascript, video, web, streaming, p2p

I want to stream video between 2 clients without passing it through the server

Each side sends real time video and also receives the other sides real time video

Is there an open source project that allows that?

Is there an API for that? I'm willing to pay

I want to create it in web app for mobile 
Js, html, Ajax, websockets, css...

Thank you so much

Comment: what video format? how do you get the video source?

Comment: As far as i know (but may be wrong) currently there is no working html5 api for capturing image or video stream from computer's built-in camera. You can use Adobe flash for capturing video stream from camera but if so, you would probably use flash for transmission too (maybe look at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/p2p_apps_cirrus_lccs.html).

Comment: @KarolyHovarth do you have an idea for a good video format? I want it to run also on iPhone so flv doesn't help... Also ur 2nd question - i want help also in capturing video.

Comment: @TomaszGawel thanks for your help. Is this also on iPhone?

Comment: For iphone you surely can NOT use flash :). I don't know if iphone's UIWebView exposes api for capturing video. But surely you can do this with native app (I would stick to that :)).

Comment: ohh i thought you had some ideas. In short: this is not possible.

Comment: Is this on mobile devices, or on desktop machines, or both? (Please re-tag appropriately).

Answer (score 0):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org) has a built in streaming server, as well as the gui it can be use via the comand line so could be scripted to suit your requirements

http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/

Answer (score 0):

If you stream video directly from one client to another, then you have to understand between two networking models: client-to-server and peer-to-peer.
Server usually is static machine, with networking infrastructure, static ip and many things that allows accessibility by public.
With peer-to-peer you will face many problems, first of them is going through NAT when you creating socket for receiving. One of client might need to create socket to accept connection, and second to accept. They might do both simultaneously and stick to first connected.
Streaming video using web is not possible right now. There is only some beta development happening for Chrome and FireFox that will be publicly available not really soon.
As well you can't establish peer-to-peer connection using WebSockets.

So there is no way doing it using Web technologies.
You might want to have a look into native Mobile development, but there you will face problems with peer-to-peer connections as well.